# Objectify embedded maps fail to retrieve

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore, objectify, expando

I am using Objectify as a data access layer in my GoogleAppEngine hosted application.

The problem comes when I try to persist a map. My bean looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Cached
class MyBean{
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public MyBean(){}

    //getters and setters below
}
```

First of all note that the map 'parameters' is not private, it was throwing a JRE exception.
When saving the map everything goes well. When retreiving it from the DataStore it fails.

My workaround is to use the @Serialized annotation. This is just a workaround since what I want to acheive is to use the [expando](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#The_Expando_Class) feature of GAE Datastore.

According to the [objectify doc](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify?wl=en#Embedded_Maps) I'm doing the right operations.

Exception details:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.loadSingleValue(Transmog.java:364)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.load.EmbeddedMapSetter.safeSet(EmbeddedMapSetter.java:65)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.load.CollisionDetectingSetter.set(CollisionDetectingSetter.java:37)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.loadSingleValue(Transmog.java:359)
>     at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.load(Transmog.java:340)   at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.toObject(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:203)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl$ToObjectIterator.translate(QueryImpl.java:668)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl$ToObjectIterator.translate(QueryImpl.java:657)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingIterator.next(TranslatingIterator.java:35)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedded maps were poorly supported in Objectify3, and should not have been publicly announced.  The section on @Embedded Map has been removed from the Objectify3 documentation.

Objectify4 supports maps extensively, including these expando-style maps:

- Map  (or any primitive)
- Map (key references)
- Map (embedded classes

In addition, there is a @Mapify annotation that lets you take a normal collection of objects, pick one property out as a key, and store that as a Map.

Unfortunately Objectify4's documentation is not ready at this time.  However, the source code is in active use by several parties.  If you feel daring, build from trunk.

Comment: Is there another place appart from the SVN repo in which I can get the 4ofy 4 lib ?

Comment: Yes, here:  http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/maven/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/4.0a3/objectify-4.0a3.jar

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using Objectify 4 - I've upgraded my app and found it fairly easy to do. I much prefer the support for fields of the type Map in particular.

To answer the question, you should never put `@Embedded` onto an array containing only primitives. So you don't need to specify `@Embedded` on your map because String is primitive in the Google App Engine Datastore.